# devise 2 models 2 views problem with path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

**context**:

> *rails* 3.0.3
>
> *devise*  1.1.5 and 1.2rc

i have following devise rdoc

```
rails g devise:install

rails g devise user

rails g devise employee

rails g devise:views users

rails g devise:views employees
```

routes.rb

> devise_for :users
>
> devise_for :employees, :path => 'admin'

devise.rb

> config.scoped_views = true

rake routes gives

> new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                                        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
>
> ```
>                 user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                        {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
>
>         destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)                       {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
>
>                user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
>
>            new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                   {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
>
>           edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
>
>                              PUT    /users/password(.:format)                       {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
>
>                  user_unlock POST   /users/unlock(.:format)                         {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/unlocks"}
>
>              new_user_unlock GET    /users/unlock/new(.:format)                     {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/unlocks"}
>
>                              GET    /users/unlock(.:format)                         {:action=>"show", :controller=>"devise/unlocks"}
>
>         new_employee_session GET    /admin/sign_in(.:format)                        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
>
>             employee_session POST   /admin/sign_in(.:format)                        {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
>
>     destroy_employee_session GET    /admin/sign_out(.:format)                       {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
>
>            employee_password POST   /admin/password(.:format)                       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
>
>        new_employee_password GET    /admin/password/new(.:format)                   {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
>
>       edit_employee_password GET    /admin/password/edit(.:format)                  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
>
>                              PUT    /admin/password(.:format)                       {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
> ```

a mailer views  users or employees are

`link_to 'Change my password', edit_user_password_url(@resource, :reset_password_token => @resource.reset_password_token)`

`link_to 'Change my password', edit_employee_password_url(@resource, :reset_password_token => @resource.reset_password_token)`

But if i submit form i have this error (*for user or employee*)

> TypeError in Devise/passwords#create
>
> Showing /app/views/users/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb where line #8 raised:
>
> can't convert String into Hash
>
> 8: <%= link_to 'Change my password', edit_employee_password_url(@resource, :reset_password_token => @resource.reset_password_token) %>

if you have an idea ?

Comment: I tried to use  *url_for* instead of *edit_user_password_url* but i have the same error

Comment: ok, the solution is in **application_controller.rb**
add
`ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "http://domain.com"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialy posted Mar 7 2011

The solution are in application_controller.rb.

add

`ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "http://domain.com"`